# Construct the joint probability mass function of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Two fair dice are thrown. Let $X$ be the random variable that represents the
> maximum obtained on any of the two dice and $Y$ the one which denotes the sum of what was obtained in both dice. Construct the joint probability mass function of $X$ and $Y$.

Any suggestions for how to define that function?

Comment: First get $X$ and $Y$ separately, maybe? That must not be very difficult, right?

Comment: Honest dice are much more reliable than lying dice.

Comment: $Y$ takes values from $2,3,...,12$ and $X$ from $1,2,..,6$. Draw a $6\times6$ table with rows $(D1)$ and columns $(D2)$ labelled $1,2,...,6$ and in each cell write the maximum and sum of the row and column indices.

Comment: In the future, your questions will be improved by the use of [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting the mathematical symbols (as was done for you here in the edit by @OttavioBartenor).

Comment: thanks for the comments! Just one last detail. How would you define $E[X]$

Comment: @callculus: One of the dice is a knight, the other a knave...

Comment: @BrianTung Nice. I didn´t know that this special situation has a special name,even though I already knew it. You never stop learning.

Comment: @callculus: You can credit (or blame) Raymond Smullyan for that. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch for a solution:** first find the probability mass function of $Z:=(X,Y)$ (namely $f_Z$), and from here you can find the probability mass function of $R:=(\max\{X,Y\},X+Y)$ (namely $f_R$) by the relation

$$
f_R(a,b)=\Pr [\max\{X,Y\}= a, X+Y= b]=\sum_{(j,k)\in A}f_{Z} (j,k)\\ A:=\{(j,k)\in \{1,\ldots ,6\}^2:\max\{j,k\}= a \,\land\, j+k=b \}\\
=\{(j,k)\in\{1,\ldots 6\}^2:\max\{j,k\}=a\,\land\, \min\{j,k\}=b-a\}
$$

As the support space is tiny you can do it using a table of $6\times 10$ entries (files for the values of $\max\{X,Y\}$ and columns for the values of $X+Y$), noticing that $f_R(a,b)=0$ when $b>2a$ or $a\geqslant b$, by example.